# RestKit - Nested Structure Fail

Tags: ios, json, mapping, restkit-0.20

I am currently using RestKit in our project but I am facing some issues to manage this structure:

```
{"Elements": [
    {
      "Element": {
        "id": "1",
        "property": "house",
        "_addons": [
          {
            "Links": [
              {
                "Link": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "url": "http://www.google.com"
                }
              },
              {
                "Link": {
                  "id": "3",
                  "url": "http://www.google.com"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Element": {
        "id": "2",
        "property": "garage",
        "_addons": [
          {
            "Links": [
              {
                "Link": {
                  "id": "4",
                  "url": "http://www.google.com"
                }
              },
              {
                "Link": {
                  "id": "5",
                  "url": "http://www.google.com"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Right now in the object Element, there is the property "links"  which is a `NSMutableArray` (I tried also with `NSMutableDictionary but the problem is still there). Now, 
if I try to do

`[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"_addons.Links.Link" toKeyPath:@"links" withMapping:[Link mapping]]];`

I receive an error saying that I wasn't possibile to map and there is a collection inside a collection.

The only solution I found was to include `@"_addons.Links" : @"links"` in the mapping dictionary. In this case, though, I "lose" the chance to have the mapping to Link objects and I have to do it manually. Anybody has any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say exactly what you want, but the JSON does have an array in an array so you need to deal with that somehow. Options:

1. Change the JSON
2. Create a custom transformer to take the array of arrays and convert into an array of objects
3. Use 2 mappings and relationships so the nested objects in the JSON are passed over into your object graph

Generally, the first or last option is best. You are, it seems, already half way to the last option, you just need an extra mapping and relationship.

Comment: Thanks @Wain for your help. I think I would go with the last option, since I can't change the JSON. Could you please give me a hand on it? I don't understand where I should add the extra mapping and relationship. It's the first time I use RestKit and I am quite confused.

Comment: So you need an element, an add on and a link class. Each has a mapping. And the mappings are linked with relationships.

Comment: Thanks @Wain, it works now. I had to set a custom setter for some properties (they were an array containing another array of mapped objects) but now it works as expected. Thanks again for your help!